# Parse Server how to access token for password reset

Tags: javascript, reactjs, parse-server

I am using Parse Server and have setup the config options to use a custom page for the password reset. This works fine, when you click the password reset link it takes you to my custom page.

The query parameters on the URL give me the `username` and a `token`. My plan was to use the `username` to query the User Class and get the user, and then get the `token` associated with the user to see if it matched the token in the URL.

**My problem** is I can't find where that token is — I do not see it in Parse Dashboard when I browse the User Class. And when I try to access it via a User query it comes back undefined (as I would expect since it's not there).

Here's some example code I put in my React component:

```
const { token, username } = this.props.queryParams

console.log('username from URL query params: ' + username)
console.log('token from URL query params: ' + token)

const User = Parse.Object.extend('User')
const userQuery = new Parse.Query(User)

userQuery
  .equalTo('username', username)
  .first()
  .then(
    function(user) {
      console.log('Returned username: ' + user.get('username'))
      console.log('Returned token: ' + user.get('token'))
    },
    function(error) {
      console.log('Error:')
      console.log(error)
    }
  )
```

Which logs this:

```
username from URL query params: davidhank
token from URL query params: veKHpzVgFEFCHdqfkXphz5DpD

Returned username: davidhank
Returned token: undefined
```

**My question**: Where does Parse store this token?

Comment: This wasn't the correct approach. I don't think the user token is exposed on the front end. I changed the form method to POST and built the action and corresponding inputs based on the default Parse page found here:
https://github.com/parse-community/parse-server/blob/ca286b7108197034a3ff02063a259ff12181a329/views/choose_password

Comment: Once that was in place all worked as expected.